# How to create a login, logout, signin system in html

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, passwords, logout

I searched everywhere but I couldn't get a way to create a login logout system, Most of it has how to create a login system UI but not the backend javascript, I want a login logout system like many websites do we can create an account.

Comment: it must have a system like stack overflow we can logout and log in again and create account

Comment: What server infrastructure do you use as a backend? Have you decided on which web server you want to use? A local instance of Apache? Node.js? Or do you use something like Amazon Web Services?

Comment: I don't know I'm new to this topic which would be better?

Answer (score 0):

There are a several ways to create a Auth system in web application.

One of the simple ones without a server is usage of Firebase.
You can find the docs here : https://firebase.google.com/

Or If you need a back-end to do all your needs there are another third-party applications such Auth0 and more

Hope you find this helpful.